# Choose endorsement policy "one specific org and at least one of any others" for HLF

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have one Org1 in a channel. I want to add new organizations Org2, Org3, etc one by one. Default endorsement policy for a chaincode is "any member of the organizations in the channel" which should mean that any new organization can invoke the chaincode. But I need that policy which requires endorsement from Org1 and from the owner of a peer.

It can be `AND('Org1.member', OutOf(1, 'Org1.member', 'Org2.member', 'Org3.member'))` but it means that I should update version of chaincode every time when I add a new org to the channel because a peer from the new org can't invoke the chaincode. Moreover, it requires to install the new version on every peer. It's not convenient.

Is there any way to write the endorsement policy for this situation?